# Open random file in directory (in cmd?) - C++-like or C#-like?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, cmd, c++builder

I write C# (.NET) programs and C++ (in Notepad++) scripts.

I want to write a program that opens a random file in the directory it was run in, using cmd on windows. *e.g.:*

```
C:\test > random
```

would open *C:\test\song1.mp3* or *C:\test\song2.mp3*

**Is this possible?**

**If so,** which language should I use: C++ or C#? (Or else)
*(Not what's better, lest my question be moved, but what's more suitable)*

Does C++ have file system support? (Couldn't find any easy libraries)
Can it know what directory it was run at?
Can C# be run from cmd? Or is it IDE-dependent and thus impossible?

**If no,** (no way to run from cmd without compiling) I prefer to write a **windows form** project.

Here again, C#.NET or C++Builder? (Or else)
*(Again, not what's better, but what's more suitable)*

Sorry for my incompetence. Feedback is appreciated.

**(Any better ideas are welcome)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Here the scheme (*C#* implementation):

To get all files from the current directory

```
  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    //.Where(file => ...) // <- to filter out some files
    .ToList();
```

To obtain a *random* file from `files`:

```
  private static Random s_Generator = new Random();
  ...
  String file = files[s_Generator.Next(files.Count)];
```

To open the `file`, note *shell execute* mode: let Window find out how the file will be open (i.e. `txt` via NotePad, `mp3` by media player etc.)

```
  ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(file) {
    UseShellExecute = true
  };

  using (var process = Process.Start(info)) {
    //process.WaitForExit(); // <- to wait for 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great!
I was interested in running the script from an independent cmd.exe, and not from a console application. How can I run this script from an external command line?

Comment: So you can write a CMD program (`random.exe`) on C#, implement the scheme in its `main` method and run `random.exe` as part ot `.bat` file, *script* etc.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in both c# and c++ as well.

In c++, you can use FindFirstFile and FindNextFile API's to find the files.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check them. Any idea how I can run the script from an external command line, and give it as input the directory in which the command line was run?

Comment: You can use ShellExecute API to execute the script.